# When creating a component with react, when should i call the libraries 'react' and 'react-dom'?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, create-react-app

I've been studying React for a while and just now started developing my own apps with it when i noticed i don't really know the difference between the `react` and `react-dom` libraries, i know that 'react' is the JavaScript library and `react-dom` is the library which provides methods for me to interact with the DOM, but nothing seems to happen when i don't import them (i use the create-react-app environment so that could be it). That being said, here's how i normally create a component:

```
import React from 'react';

function ComponentName () {
  return(
    <div>
      <!-- Component code -->
    </div>
  )
}

export {ComponentName};
```

So what's the difference between the code on top, this:

```
import React from 'react-dom';

function ComponentName () {
  return(
    <div>
      <!-- Component code -->
    </div>
  )
}
```

and this?

```
import React from 'react-dom';

function ComponentName () {
  return(
    <div>
      <!-- Component code -->
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Your last two code blocks are exactly the same...? (I don't mean they do the same thing. I mean they're literally character-for-character identical.)

Comment: [With the new transform, you can use JSX without importing React](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**React**

For React, you must import React from 'react'. You need to import the default, and you need to name it React. This is because anytime you write JSX code like  or , this JSX code is transpiled and uses React.createElement(). So, you need to have access to the React object as it is named.

**NOTE:** **React 17 and some older specified major versions now include a new JSX transform that does not require this explicit React import.**

**ReactDOM**

For ReactDOM, however, you are probably mostly concerned with the DOM-related methods that are part of the default export, methods like render() or hydrate(). Because that's what you'll probably be using, you can name your import module anything you want. So, you could do something like this:

```
import FooBar from 'react-dom'
FooBar.render(someElement)
```

This does work, but the standard convention is to call the imported module ReactDOM, as that would make your code more understandable to anyone else looking at it.

Comment: Ooooooh i see. I think i'm using React 17 then, since i removed the import tag and nothing happened. You think i should keep importing it safety measures and readability or no?

Comment: There's no need, cleaner code. 
also, it should be pretty straight forward to anyone who uses React and stays up to date with it to know why it isn't there.

Comment: *"...you can name your import module anything you want..."* `FooBar` in `import FooBar from 'react-dom'` is the *default export*, not the module. (There's a different form that lets you import a *module namespace object* for a module, which is `import * as FooBar from "react-dom";` though that's rarely what you want.)

Answer (score 1):

Create React App handles using `react-dom` for you (in `index.js`/`index.ts` in the `src` directory).

Import `React` from `"react"`, not from `"react-dom"`. If you're using the a recent version, you only need to do this if you're using the `React` object in your code (for instance using `React.memo`, although you could use `import {memo} from "react"` instead). You no longer need to import `React` just for JSX ([details](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html)).

Basically:

- `"react"` is the main library
- `"react-dom"` provides features for using React with the DOM
- There are also other libraries for using React without a DOM (for instance, for server-side rendering)

Comment: Precisely what i was thinking, thanks for your help!